# Visual Studio Code- Emmet not working, error codes for all suggested fixes thus far

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

So I'm new to coding but downloaded Visual Studio Code as my text editor- free, robust, well-supported... what more is there to ask?

When I downloaded VSC, I found I couldn't get Emmet to work for anything I attempted, including HTML.

I searched and watched YouTube tutorials, asked freeCodeCamp, looked on Reddit, and explored this platform.

Here on Stack Overflow, I was told to try entering the following lines of code in the settings.json:

```
"emmet.excludeLanguages": [],
"emmet.includeLanguages": {"markdown": "html"},
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
```

The lines were added, as suggested; however, the following error code continued to pop up:
* "Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again."

I also watched the introductory videos from VSC to see if there was anything I could learn from them.  Even in those videos, Emmet seems to work without a hitch.

I'm frustrated and not sure what needs to be done to activate Emmet.  I'm looking to this community because I've been told y'all are the best of the best in terms of coding knowlege and helpfulness.  If I'm doing something wrong I'll GLADLY fix it.  Any and all help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please provide information about your operating system.
But looking at the error message, I think there are something wrong with your settings.json. Open settings,json and see if there are errors, they are underlined with squiggly red.

Comment: `"Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again."`  That error has nothing to do with emmet.  It just means that your settings.json is dirty/unsaved or has problems in it (like invalid json).  Fix those - see the Problems panel for info on any problems in that file and then try to add your `emmet` settings you mentioned and then report back here.